# Data truncated for column 'x'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the distance between two points, that works fine, but what I am having issues with are these warning messages:

> Data truncated for column 'x' at row 32
>   Data truncated for column 'x' at row 82
>   Data truncated for column 'x' at row 89

This is the function I have created:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `GetDistance`(`lat1` numeric(10, 7), `lon1` numeric(10, 7), `lat2` numeric(10, 7), `lon2` numeric(10, 7))
RETURNS decimal(10,7)
BEGIN 
      DECLARE x decimal(10, 7);
      DECLARE pi decimal(21, 20);
      SET pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
      SET x  = round(sin(lat1 * pi / 180)
        * sin(lat2 * pi / 180)
        + cos(lat1 * pi / 180)
        * cos(lat2 * pi / 180)
        * cos((lon2 * pi / 180) - (lon1 * pi / 180)), 7);
    SET x = round(atan((sqrt( 1- power( x, 2))) / x), 7);
    RETURN round((1.852 * 60.0 * ((x / pi) * 180)) / 1.609344, 7);
END
```

Here are the two columns for `lat1`, `lon1` and `lat2`, `lon2`

```
CREATE TABLE `world_cities` (
    `latitude` DECIMAL(10,7) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `longitude` DECIMAL(10,7) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Here are the max/min values:

```
"max(latitude)"     "min(latitude)"     "max(longitude)"     "min(longitude)"
"82.4833330"        "-54.9333330"       "180.0000000"        "-179.9833333"
```

So, what is causing this warning message?

Here is the query calling the function:

```
SELECT city, region, population, latitude, longitude,
GetDistance(@lat, @lon, latitude, longitude) as dist
FROM world_cities
WHERE MBRContains(LineString(Point(@lat + @kmRange / 111.1, @lon + @kmRange / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat)))), Point(@lat - @kmRange / 111.1, @lon - @kmRange / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))))), location)
and city_id != @city_id
order By dist;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By declaring 'x' as a `double`, and setting my return type to a `double` I was able to fix the issue.

Changing this:

```
DECLARE x decimal(10, 7);
```

To this:

```
DECLARE x double;
```

Answer (score 0):

You return `RETURNS decimal(10,7)` and at the same time calculate distance which is much more than `decimal(10,7)`.
The value of `arctan(a)` should be between `-pi/2` and `pi/2` (`-1.57 ... 1.57`).
Let's assume `x = pi/2`, so `x / pi = (pi/2) / pi = 1/2`.
Your distance value will be over `6000` which is bigger than `decimal(10,7)`.

Try to change `RETURNS decimal(10,7)` to `RETURNS decimal(11,7)` and it should cover all possible values and work without warnings.

Comment: Nope, changing that still gives me warnings.

Comment: @Alex That's actually an issue here, but I realized that it would cause "Out of range value for column..." warning instead of "Data truncated".

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `GetDistance`(`lat1` numeric(10, 7), `lon1` numeric(10, 7), `lat2` numeric(10, 7), `lon2` numeric(10, 7))
RETURNS decimal(10,7)
BEGIN
      DECLARE x decimal(10, 7);
      DECLARE pi decimal(21, 20);
      SET pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
      SET x  = cast(sin(lat1 * pi / 180)
        * sin(lat2 * pi / 180)
        + cos(lat1 * pi / 180)
        * cos(lat2 * pi / 180)
        * cos((lon2 * pi / 180) - (lon1 * pi / 180)) as decimal(10, 7));
    SET x = cast(atan((sqrt( 1- power( x, 2))) / x) as decimal(10, 7));
    RETURN cast((1.852 * 60.0 * ((x / pi) * 180)) / 1.609344 as decimal(10, 7));
END
```

I'm suspecting a floating point approximation error.